# Cannot assign self as delegate in property initializer

Tags: ios, swift, swift-playground

I am getting a strange error message when I try to access self when initializing a property on my class.  It seems like my class has a weird type.

This is the error:

```
Cannot assign a value of type 'ViewController -> () ViewController' to a value of type 'ModelControllerDelegate?'
```

This is the code, simple example in a playground:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

protocol ModelControllerDelegate
    {
    func modelControllerDidFinishTask()
    }

class ModelController
    {
    var delegate : ModelControllerDelegate?
    }

class ViewController : UIViewController, ModelControllerDelegate
    {
    var modelController : ModelController =
        {
        let controller = ModelController()
        controller.delegate = self
        return controller
        }()

    func modelControllerDidFinishTask()
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to use `self` when not fully initialised. Might work if you use a lazy initialisation:

```
lazy var modelController : ModelController = { ...
```

Answer (score 2):

When initialising a property with a closure like this the closure is run before the instance is fully initialised. This means there are a few things you can't do here:

1. Access other property values
2. Use self
3. Call any instance methods

To get around this you could either initialise modelController entirely in the ViewController's init, or at least defer the setting of its delegate until then.